# Sequelize: how to use `scope` inside `include`?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I want to ask if it's possible to use the scope of the associate model inside `include` option?

In my case, there are two models, `User` and `Code`:

```
const ACTIVE_FIELDS = ['fullname', 'idCard']
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  uid: DataTypes.STRING,
  fullname: DataTypes.TEXT,
  idCard: DataTypes.STRING,
  province: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {
  scopes: {
    activated: {
      where: ACTIVE_FIELDS.reduce((condition, field) => {
        condition[field] = {[sequelize.Op.ne]: null}
        return condition
      }, {}),
    },
    inProvinces: (provinces) => ({
      where: {
        province: {
          [sequelize.Op.in]: provinces,
        },
      },
    }),
  },
})

const Code = sequelize.define('Code', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  uid: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {});
```

`Code` belongs to `User` through `uid`

```
Code.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'uid',
  targetKey: 'uid',
  as: 'user',
})
```

I want to select a random `Code` of users who are activated and in particular provinces. Is there any way to reuse `activated` and `inProvinces` scope so it may look like:

```
const randomCode = (provinces) =>
  Code.findOne({
    include: [{
      model: User,
      as: 'user',
      scopes: ['activated', {method: ['inProvinces', provinces]}],
      attributes: [],
      required: true,
    }],
    order: sequelize.random(),
  })
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try attaching your scope to the actual model.... it worked for me.

```
Code.findOne({
  include: [{
    model: User.unscoped() 
  }],
})
```

@eee Update - to be more clear:

```
Code.findOne({
  include: [{
    model: User.scope('activated', {method: ['inProvinces', provinces]}) 
  }],
})
```

i think this should work...

Comment: I don't really get it. Could you elaborate please?